# How to print expression in color using Print function?

Tags: style

I am wondering how would you print the expression with color using function `Print`. For example, I tried the code below but the output of print function is just black. Is there a method to choose the color for both `my result` and `x+y+z` in the code below?

```
result = x + y + z; 

Print[" my result =  ", result]
```

Comment: Use `Style`. Anything you wrap in `Style` will display with that `Style`. You can do much more interesting things than just `Print`.

Comment: I tried that but `result` above can be any expression not just `x+y+z`. So how do I use style?

Comment: You read the documentation for [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) and then it's obvious... But if you need an explicit answer: e.g. `Style[result, Red]`. Get rid of the `Print`. You don't need it. Use `Row` instead.

Comment: I'd like to color both `myresult` and the expression of `result`. How can I use both in `Style`?

Comment: Look up `Row`. And read the documentation. Please. It lays it out.